# When does abstractSSHclass instantiate a concrete class instance in robotframework ssh library

Tags: python, abstract-class, robotframework

When using the keyword ""Open Connection" " I know why  ssh robot library  uses an abstract client? It has 2  concrete implementations. Java and Python.
I'm not sure when the concrete implementation is invoked and how the framework  chooses between the python and java implmentations?

The keyword "open connection"  is described here

https://github.com/robotframework/SSHLibrary/blob/master/src/SSHLibrary/library.py

```
def open_connection(self, host, alias=None, port=22, timeout=None,
                        newline=None, prompt=None, term_type=None, width=None,
                        height=None, path_separator=None, encoding=None):


client = SSHClient(host, alias, port, timeout, newline, prompt,
                           term_type, width, height, path_separator, encoding)
```

It  invokes this:

https://github.com/robotframework/SSHLibrary/blob/master/src/SSHLibrary/abstractclient.py

```
class AbstractSSHClient(object):
    """Base class for the SSH client implementation.
    This class defines the public API. Subclasses (:py:class:`pythonclient.
    PythonSSHClient` and :py:class:`javaclient.JavaSSHClient`) provide the
    language specific concrete implementations.
    """
```

But when using an abstract client when is the chosen concrete implementation invoked in python and how is it selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concrete class is instantiated inside the "Get Connection" keyword -- the method get_connection in library.py:

```
...
from .client import SSHClient
...
def get_connection(self, index_or_alias=None, index=False, host=False,
                   alias=False, port=False, timeout=False, newline=False,
                   prompt=False, term_type=False, width=False, height=False,
                   encoding=False):
...
    client = SSHClient(host, alias, port, timeout, newline, prompt,
                       term_type, width, height, path_separator, encoding)
```

In the above code, `SSHClient` is imported from client.py, which is where the decision is made to use the python or java client.

At the time that I write this, `client.py` is nothing more than a single if statement:

```
if sys.platform.startswith('java'):
    from javaclient import JavaSSHClient as SSHClient
else:
    from pythonclient import PythonSSHClient as SSHClient
```